# C++ Operator override copy constructor pointer error segment flaut

Tags: c++, constructor, copy

I have a problem when run my program and i found out that the error(segmentation fault) is from this following code:

```
char* OSname;
char* HWname; 
Computer(const char* a,const char* b){
    strcpy(OSname,a); strcpy(HWname,b);
}
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Out of interest, why do you mention a copy constructor? Surely a copy constructor would look like `Computer(const Computer & other)`

Comment: Yes i have Computer(const Computer &tmp) in my program and it had the strcpy() too. So I only mention the error once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char* OSname;` declares a pointer but doesn't point anywhere. If you wish to copy a string somewhere you need some meory, so must either allocate some memory (remembering to free it) or just use an array.

In either case you then need to make sure there is enough memory for a full `strcpy` and that the copied `char *` is actually null terminated or use `strncpy`.

Since you have tagged this C++ it is worth thinking about using a `std::string` instead:

```
std::string OSname;
std::string HWname; 
Computer(const std::string & a,const std::string & b){
    OSname = a; HWname=b;
}
```

This is very likely to avoid your problem.

Comment: The exercise require OSname and HWname to be a pointer and i am not good at pointer.

Comment: Complain to whoever set the exercise!

Comment: You'll need something like `char *OSname = new char[strlen(a) + 1];` before doing the strcpy and don't forget to `delete[]` later.

Comment: using `char *OSname = new char[strlen(a) + 1];` have this error terminate called after throwing an instance of `int` but it fine if i only use `new char`;